# Lightning <InputRichText> isnt working

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In the below Code snipets,Lightning  is not working  properly. By default I set "myVal" attribute value to "annappa" and tried to display that value in inputRichtext. Please let me know the mistake.

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute name="myVal" type="String" default="annappa" />
<lightning:inputRichText value="{!v.myVal}" >
</lightning:inputRichText>
```

application:

```
<aura:application >
<c:InputRich/>
</aura:application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine for me. Please see the screenshot below.
[image]

My component code is

```
<aura:component >
     <aura:attribute name="myVal" type="String" default="annappa" />
     <lightning:inputRichText value="{!v.myVal}" />
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
    <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
    <script>
    var accountId = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}";
        $Lightning.use("c:aimiaLgtrichTextInputapp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:aimiaLgtrichTextInput",
               {},
                "myVal",
                function(cmp) {
                    console.log("Component created!");
                    console.log(cmp);
                });
            });
    </script>
    <div id="myVal"></div>
</apex:page>
```

i am not able to get component in vf page